# How to connect multiple monitors to an iMac

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, imac, mini-dvi

Hi is it possible to connect 2 monitors to an IMac?  I am able to connect a second monitor but would like to be able to connect one more.  I looked into using a KVM switch but this it seems is for the opposite.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply show the same thing on all external monitors, all you need is a device called a splitter (e.g. http://www.maplin.co.uk/module.aspx?moduleno=25375 for VGA; you can get similar things for most types of cable).

If you want to display different things, you need something like a Matrox GXM: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/ . It's a little box that pretends to be a monitor twice as large as your individual monitors, the splits the signal between them. So, for instance, if you want to connect two 1024x768 monitors to your iMac, it'll appear to the computer as one 2048x768 monitor. There are a few limitations - like the inability to designate *one* of the external monitors as your main one, only both - but other than adding another graphics card (not a practical option with an iMac) it's the only solution.